# Text field without form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a web page and I want to do something with user input text. Normally, `<input type="text" />` is used inside a `<form>` nesting and setting input without form attribute is not acceptable in html strict schema. I want to avoid `<form>`, but still want some text field to use with JavaScript.

I am seeking an example with an option for text input and alert input data on click of a button, with/without jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org/check), this passes HTML 4.01 Strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="text" value="hi"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this passes XHTML 1.0 Strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="text" value="hi" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that `<input>` is an inline tag and thus needs to be inside something that accepts such tags (`<body>` does not).

Answer (score 2):

Having a closer look at the [**DTD**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html), an `input` element is part of the `inline` (lets call it) group:

```
<!ENTITY % formctrl "INPUT | SELECT | TEXTAREA | LABEL | BUTTON">

<!-- %inline; covers inline or "text-level" elements -->
<!ENTITY % inline "#PCDATA | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %special; | %formctrl;">
```

So wherever `inline` is allowed, so is `input`. That means you don't need a `form`.

E.g. in a `div`:

```
<!ENTITY % flow "%block; | %inline;">
(...)
<!ELEMENT DIV - - (%flow;)*            -- generic language/style container -->
```

But **not** as you mentioned in a comment, in the `body`:

```
<!ELEMENT BODY O O (%block;|SCRIPT)+ +(INS|DEL) -- document body -->
```

(I think it goes without saying that `block` does not contain `inline`).

Answer (score -1):

It's perfectly OK to have an input element without a form. Where does it say it's not allowed?

Comment: I am using microsoft expression web and it is showing error, saying that in html 4.01 strict <body> cannot contain tag <input>

Comment: @blasteralfred: Because `body` is not allowed to have `inline` elements.

Comment: @blasteralfred: It's not the lack of a form - it's the fact that body may not directly contain inline elements. Put your input inside another block element and it should validate.

Comment: can you do me a fiddle as i mentioned??

Comment: @blasteralfred: All you need to do is add one element to make it valid. Surely you can do that yourself.